# Writing to Android device with Cordova file system plugin, different AndroidPersistentFileLocation values

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, persistence

I'm writing a Javascript function to write to a text file on an Android device using the Cordova file system plugin. If in my config.xml file I use the recommended setting:

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
```

the code fails when calling `fs.root.getFile()` with `INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR`. But if I use:

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

the code creates and writes to the file as expected.

**What can be the reason for this and will using `Compatibility` instead of `Internal` have any negative impact on my app?**

Code that writes to file:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
  function(fs) {
    var filePath = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory.replace(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory,"");
    var fileName = filePath + "acuDevice.txt";
    console.log("acuDevice fileName:"+fileName);
    fs.root.getFile(fileName, { create:true, exclusive:false },
      function(fileEntry) {
        console.log("acuDevice fileEntry:"+JSON.stringify(fileEntry));
        fileEntry.createWriter(
          function (fileWriter) {
            fileWriter.onerror = function (err) { console.log("acuDevice write failed:"+JSON.stringify(err)); };
            fileWriter.onwriteend = writeComplete;
            fileWriter.write("hello acuDevice world");
          }
        ); // createWriter
      },
      fileErrorHandler
    ); // getFile
  },
  fileErrorHandler
); // requestFileSystem
```